# How do I pool Oracle connections in Tomcat?

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I'm unclear on the appropriate way to set up connections to an Oracle RAC database in Tomcat via context.xml. THIS method works for me:

```
<Resource
     name="jdbc/mydb"
     auth="Container"
     type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:<connection details>"
     username="<username>"
     password="<account>"
     maxTotal="150"
     maxIdle="10"
     />
```

But is that using a connection pool?  I tried adding `factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"`, as suggested at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html, and mysteriously with that one change, I started getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

If I instead try `type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"` and `factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"` I get:

```
Error: Unable to obtain a JDBC connection from Datasource:
java.lang.Exception: Error: Unable to obtain a JDBC connection from Datasource:
```

I've looked all over, but it's not clear to me what the best practice is for this. Ideas?

Comment: Yes, it looks like your first method - that works - should use a connection pool.

Comment: Do you mean pooling is built into the Oracle driver, or into Tomcat?

Without directly referencing the pooling factories?

Comment: Tomcat has a default connection pool called `DBCP 2` - at least in Tomcat versions 8 and 9. See [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_(DBCP_2)_Configurations). I have used it in the same way as your first (working) example - your `Resource` configuration. It was for MySQL, in my case. I have never used that `factory` parameter.

Comment: Just to add: There are plenty of alternatives to the default Tomcat pool. I have also used [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) - but in that case, it was configured in the web app's Java code, not via a resource entry.

Comment: I guess this confuses me, because in the Tomcat documentation link on JDBC pools, it says " factory is required, and the value should be org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"

Comment: I took a closer look at this, because - yes - it is confusing. In a new Tomcat 9 install, I used 2 `Resource` variations: (1) using only `type="javax.sql.DataSource"`, and (2) using `factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"` with `type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"`. In both cases, I used `initialSize="4"`. With set-up (1), I got far too many connections created. With set-up (2) I got the 4 I was expecting. So, both settings worked for me, but (a) did not appear to be using the pooled connections as expected, whereas (b) did. **My comment above seems to be wrong.**

Comment: Ok, your settings seemed to work for me Andrew... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*I am adding this answer to clarify my earlier comments, and for future visitors to this question.*

**Summary**

Both of the following approaches will use DB connection pools:

- Use Tomcat's newer, default DBCP 2 pool with `type="javax.sql.DataSource"`.
- Use Tomcat's older JDBC pool with `factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"` and `type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"`.

I don't know enough about the differences to give any strong recommendations re. using one over the other.

**The Default DBCP 2 Tomcat Pool**

To make use of the default Tomcat DB connection pool, via a JNDI resource, you should follow the instructions provided on this Tomcat documentation page: [JNDI Datasource How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Specifically, you need to use `type="javax.sql.DataSource"`.

Here is a very basic resource configuration - not suitable for production, but useful to illustrate the approach. And it's for MySQL not Oracle, so there will be some adjustments needed:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/my_db" 
          auth="Container" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          initialSize="5"
          username="db_user"
          password="***"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytestdb" />
```

When using `initialSize="5"`, I saw the 5 expected connections on the DB server.

In the JVM, a connection pool was created - as shown in this VisualVM heap dump:

[image]

Here we can see that the pool is created, it has 5 connection objects, and it is using `Tomcat DBCP` - which, in turn, is a fork of Apache Commons `DBCP 2`.

DBCP 2 provides support for JDBC 4.1.

**Tomcat's Home-Grown JDBC Pool**

If you look at the Tomcat documentation on this other page - [The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) - you will see different guidance.

Specifically it states that you need both of the following in your `<Resource>`:

```
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
```

If you use this, you will also be using a DB connection pool - but it will be based on the older Tomcat JDBC pool package:

[image]

In this example, I used `initialSize="3"`.

In the Tomcat documentation this is presented as "a new connection pool" (it *was* a replacement for the previously used `Commons DBCP 1.x`). It's *not* as new as the Tomcat default DBCP 2 solution. I think the documentation wording is out-of-date, now. And somewhat confusing, because of that.

**Additional Notes**

Notes from a member of the Tomcat commit team (see [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64106#c1)):

> *Tomcat JDBC is Tomcat's "home grown" database connection pooling and does not use poolPreparedStatements*
>
> *Tomcat DBCP is Tomcat's package renamed fork of Apache Commons DBCP 2.*
>
> *Tomcat DBCP is used by default.*

You can always choose to implement a pool directly in your code, without using a JNDI `<Resource>` annotation. There are many available options.

(In my initial tests, there was a problem with my Tomcat installation which resulted in the creation of too many connections for DBCP 2. That misled me, initially).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [Universal Connection Pool (UCP)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jjucp/toc.htm) is a Java connection pool that you can use as well. It is feature rich and works well with Oracle RAC, DG etc., Check out [UCPServlet](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/java/jdbc/Tomcat_Servlet) for an example.